# how to show a full page image on website home page on load with fadeout effect

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

i'm working on wordpress with the-bootstrap theme.i want to load a full page image on home page as soon as my site opens.and want to fadeout the image in few seconds but unable to do so.

i have tried the bootstrap modal but the image is not coming as full page. how can i achieve it.

i have tried this:

```
<div id="downloads" class="modal hide fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-body">
<img src="http://pearlacademy.com/whatsnext/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Learner.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#downloads').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: `model()`???? is there any function like this

Comment: @Prashant: yes in bootstrap

Comment: Are you getting alert ? And have include all files for **Bootstrap** ?

Answer (score 0):

From your question. i think you want fadeout effect on image. If yes, your solution is

```
<script type="text/javascript">//
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#downloads').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

#### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/azz2v2m8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Jquery().onload(function ($){
 ...css ().fadeout ().slow ()
  })
```

Use onload ()